# Hibernate doesnot resume last state

Tags: 15.04, suspend, hibernate

I enabled hibernation following this steps:
[How to enable hibernation in 15.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614662/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-15-04)

I can now see "hibernate" option and also hibernate seems to turn my computer off. But when I turn back on, it is like a regular boot, with all windows closed. Please help.

Also, 
`sudo pm-is-supported` gives following result :

```
$ sudo pm-is-supported
pm-is-supported [--suspend | --hibernate | --suspend-hybrid ]
```

Hibernating from the command prompt using `sudo pm --hibernate` does same thing. Screen goes off, comes back in 1-2 seconds, and computers turns off. Starting closes all my work and boot like a regular boot.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need also (like me) to **add the `resume` parameter to kernel boot options in grub** --making sure you enter your swap partition there correctly and its size is right-- as per: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate

However, I experience 2 minor problems after having the "Hibernate" feature working as above:

1) Grub2 menu switches to an error mode (probably because of a minor pm/acpi error) waiting for **30 seconds**, as a result of which I needed to manually modify my grub.cfg file from `timeout=30` to `timeout=0` which might require booting from a live USB disk when there's a major error.

2) Hibernate feature apparently comes into effect on my computer after **network manager is shutdown**, resulting in that I log in disconnected, which requires **restarting network manager**, for which I already have this startup script in place: [How to persist on a wifi connection after disconnection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627600/how-to-persist-on-a-wifi-connection-after-disconnection/629757#629757)